# Intellij can't find helper classes under Test directories

Tags: java, intellij-idea

My project structure in the module is as follows.

```
[src]
    [java] <- production classes, marked as SOURCES
[test]
    [java] <- test and helper classes, marked as TESTS
        [com]
            [company]
                TestUtils.java
```

The `test/java` path contains JUnits, as well as helper classes which are shared between different sets of tests. These helper classes are not being compiled when the path is marked as Tests. **It does work correctly if I mark it as Sources.** It's almost like IntelliJ expects to ONLY find unit tests there so it is ignoring the other classes if you mark it as Tests.

```
Error:(48, 16) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable TestUtils
  location: class com.company.TestUtils
```

Is there any way to mix this type of helper classes in the same directories as tests while marking the directory as Tests in the module? This would make my life way easier by being able to create tests for classes with one action (ctrl+shift+t).

Comment: What doesn't compile? Which class causes this error? Where is that class located?

Comment: @JBNizet, any non-JUnit class under the test directory does not compile. You can see the error that the compiler `cannot find symbol`.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example. There is no theoretical reason why any class located in `test` source folder cannot see your `TestUtils` class.

Comment: Please use maven and stick to the standard directories. If you're doing anything else then you're just asking for trouble.